# SharePoint2016 OnPrem - Cannot connect to config database when Add new server to existing farm

Tags: database, configuration, sharepoint-2016, on-premises-instances

We today have an SharePoint 2016 OnPrem environment with 2 servers, 1 FE and 1 ApplicationSearch. We now like to install a new server for only search and add it to the exisiting environment. We have installed SharePoint 2016 and also installed the same level of patches (KB5002397 and KB5002370)  as the old servers and the same LanguagePack (German).
We have in cliconfig.exe set an alias to the SQL server for the databases
When we run SharePoint Configuration Wizard on the new server and in the Specify Configuration Database Settings part add Alias-name into Database server and click Retrieve Database Names we receive the correct Configuration Database but when we click Next we get Error message
“Failed to connect to the existing server farm located at the specified database server and database name. The database name is not a valid configuration database”

We have checked so the account we are run the configuration Wizard on have SharePoint_Shell_Access.
When we start SharePoint Management Shell as Administrator we get
“The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyID are not registrated”

What have we missed and how to solve this the best way so we can get the new server connected into the environment

Comment: You should rather ask this question on https://superuser.com, not here.